# how to disregard negative numbers in a ranged search

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following if statement in a MVC controller

```
                        if (vm.MileageLower > 0)
                    {
                        filter = new dtReport_v10_r1.QueueFilter();

                        filter.DataSource1_ID = 20;
                        filter.Formula1_ID = 0;
                        filter.ColumnName1 = "mileage";
                        filter.ColumnDesc1 = "mileage";
                        filter.Operator = ">";
                        filter.ValueList = vm.MileageLower.ToString();
                        queueObject.QueueFilters.Add(filter);
                        filter = null;
                    }

                    if (vm.MileageUpper > 0)
                    {
                        filter = new dtReport_v10_r1.QueueFilter();
                        filter.DataSource1_ID = 20;
                        filter.Formula1_ID = 0;
                        filter.ColumnName1 = "mileage";
                        filter.ColumnDesc1 = "mileage";
                        filter.Operator = "<=";
                        filter.ValueList = vm.MileageUpper.ToString();
                        queueObject.QueueFilters.Add(filter);
                        filter = null;
                    }
```

What is supposed to happen here is to produce a ranged search on a mvc view.  When I run the view it performs the search with no issues, however if the "mileagelower" value is zero it picks up negative numbers.

I realize that in a real world situation a vehicle is not going to have negative mileage however it is a test value that needs to be removed when searching on it.

How would I go about eliminating negative values from the search results?

Just for more information this is where the search values are created

```
                oItem = new SelectListItem() { Value = "0", Text = "Any" };
            vm.MileageList.Add(oItem);
            for (var n = 0; n <= 14000; n += 1000)
            {
                oItem = new SelectListItem();
                oItem.Value = n.ToString();
                oItem.Text = n.ToString();
                vm.MileageList.Add(oItem);
            }
            for (var n = 15000; n <= 100000; n += 15000)
            {
                oItem = new SelectListItem();
                oItem.Value = n.ToString();
                oItem.Text = n.ToString();
                vm.MileageList.Add(oItem);
            }
            for (var n = 100000; n <= 200000; n += 25000)
            {
                oItem = new SelectListItem();
                oItem.Value = n.ToString();
                oItem.Text = n.ToString();
                vm.MileageList.Add(oItem);
            }
            for (var n = 225000; n <= 400000; n += 100000)
            {
                oItem = new SelectListItem();
                oItem.Value = n.ToString();
                oItem.Text = n.ToString();
                vm.MileageList.Add(oItem);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LINQ, which is the most appropiate way in my opinion:

```
vm.MileageList.Where(x=>x.value > 0).ToList() should do the trick.
```

Or you can do a "foreach" loop on the objects :

```
var list = new List<object>();
foreach(var nObject in vm.MilageList){
  if(nObject.Value < 0)continue;
  list.Add(nobject);
}
```

Comment: Would I use this instead of the line "vm.MileageList.Add(oItem)" ?

Comment: var positiveList = vm.MileageList.Where(x=>x.value > 0); foreach(var obj in postiveList) addToList.Add(obj);